# spring longpolling example code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eclipse, spring-mvc

I can find lots of information on how Long Polling works (For example, this, and this), but no simple examples of how to implement this in code.

Basically, how would I use Apache Tomcat to serve the requests, and how would I write a simple app ( spring ) which would "long-poll" the server for new messages?

The example doesn't have to be scaleable, secure or complete, it just needs to work!
I would appreciate it if anyone could give me such a tutorial or refer any other.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest example I can come up with...

In the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/longPolling")
public String longPolling(Model model) {
  while(true) {
    // .. Do something, break when done...
    if( somethingIsDone ) {
       break;
    }
  }
  return "someResponse";
}
```

In the View calling this, you would setup an ajax call, and on a timeout simply call this again.  The idea of long polling is that the server just doesn't respond until it has something to respond with.

A better approach, if you are using Spring 3.2, is to use [DeferredResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html)
 or return a Callable from your handler method.  If you are pre-Spring 3.2, then there are several frameworks you can use to help, like Atmosphere, that work just fine with Spring. Some even have JavaScript parts to ease the client-side coding.

Comment: DeferredResult is a Spring 3.2 addition, and allows for you to pass off the created DeferredResult to a separate process.  Callable is a Java class, similar to Runnable.  Its harder to implement Callable in a way to allow a separate process to handle the response, although not impossible.  Here is a fairly decent blog on how to get DeferredResult working:  http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/13/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the already existing anwser, a more effecient "long polling" variant using the new stuff coming with Servlet 3 API (Tomcat 7) and Spring 3.2

```java
@RequestMapping("/longPolling")
public Future<String> longPolling(Model model) {
  return callSomethingWhereAFutureReturns();
}
```

The point is: The future is only "a pointer" (do not get it literally) to a result in the future. So, the dispatching thread for this request will be suspended/exit after handling the code above regardless when the future will be resolved. WHEN the future is resolved, the/a thread will be re-attached and returns the actually result (in this case, a string). But think "Spring", this could be also a POJO converted to JSON.

This does make sense only if the future result will be resolved by another thread. In a chat application, this would be another request thread with the new message (not recommended) or a dedicated dispatcher thread (better).